# I need to energize a 25 watt incandescent bulb. When that bulb burns out another 25 watt incandescent bulb will energize

Tags: current, sensor, switching

I need to provide a small amount of heat to my downstairs sink when we are away for the winter. A 25 watt incandescent bulb is fine for the job, but last year the bulb burned out at some point. I want to make a circuit that will sense when the bulb burns out and switch to another 25 watt incandescent bulb

Comment: What supplies the bulb? Is it direct grid-connected? Or is there a driver/PSU?

Comment: What is the mains voltage where you live?

Comment: Hi! Welcome here! You'll notice this is a question & answer site, and you really haven't asked a question – you just described what you want to achieve. Which is good and necessary, but you **must** ask a precise question. Probably you had some approach (or multiple), and had a question about that?

Comment: A better solution is to use a heat source that has a much longer life. Something like a *heated floor mat*, although everything I can find right now is *smart*, it may turn off after a power outage. Or, 2 light bulbs in series. At low voltage, light bulbs will last almost forever.

Comment: Radiator coolant.

Comment: Consider a 25 W wirewound resistor, which is extremely unlikely to burn out.  Much simpler than the complexity of detection and switching.

Comment: Any one of [these power resistors](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/chassis-mount-resistors/54?s=N4IgjCBcoExaBjKAzAhgGwM4FMA0IB7KAbXADYBmAFgA4KR8wyBWATjFYfBqrIHY4jVnz41O%2BGAAZJMGGS4wwzCn3oSpzZvPUxq4kLLJTBBijVE0QAXXwAHAC5QQAZXsAnAJYA7AOYgAvhKSNMzwIEiQaFh4hCQgmpIABADyABYAtphcWklpmdlGKRlZ%2BMx8ZEX5NiAOTgCqXh72ycgAstiomACubtgB%2BAC0cNDhUO5dMUSQpKFW-vNAA) screwed down onto a random piece of aluminum a few inches in area should last pretty much for ever.

Comment: @jonathanjo If they want 25W of heat they don't want a 25W resistor, it should be overrated. Since it will be left unattended I'd say at least 2x rating or 50W. And usually they need to be heat sinked.

Comment: XYproblem.info.

Comment: @GodJihyo Of course you're right about overrating.  I believe the usage is to stop a water pipe freezing, so I think the pipe is the heatsink.

Comment: 130V extended life bulbs are easily available. They are not as efficient at producing light but live longer as explained by @neil.

Comment: Not so much as a single word from DaveO, so far. Anyway, without belaboring the question and just going with it, I'd use a low-voltage primary in series with the bulb, to provide a secondary signal used to engage a second circuit should the first fail. (I have never had an incandescent fail 'closed' for very long -- should that happen the bridge melts immediately at much higher current and becomes an open almost instantly. Every failed incandescent I've opened up to look at with a microscope is always open by the time I see them.)

Comment: Look up "dehumidification heater bar" or rod. They're used in safes and pianos. I see several in 25 W. Plugs into the wall, ETL listed. Done.

Comment: @user71659 I'm used to that sort of thing being called a "tube heater" (or "tubular...") when sold for keeping rooms frost free and a little dryer.  So there's another term worth looking for, along with "electric greenhouse heater", which tend to run at a slightly higher power but have a thermostat

Comment: @jonathanjo only if it's thermally well-connected to the pipe, and that's not trivial, what with pipes being round and power resistors generally flat

Comment: Are you sure you need to use something powered for this? If you're afraid of burst pipes from freezing, wouldn't it be wiser to just drain them before you leave?

Comment: @ChrisH yes indeed, especially if the pipes aren't metal ... the basic thing I'm suggesting is if you want a heater. don't use a fragile object which coincidentally is a heater and add failsafe circuitry, use a thing designed to convert electricity into heat.  Ie, an appropriate high power resistor thermally connected in a suitable way.  Perhaps even with a close-on-rise thermostat.

Comment: @jonathanjo I'm with you on that, and added an answer with a couple of more sensible options (slightly surprised no one got there before me)

Comment: 3 months of winter counts about 2000 hours, and light bulbs usuallly are rated for 1000 hours. The reason is that the filament heats up to something like 5000 C, while you need  to keep the room at about 5 C. What a waste of tech. Just use some cheap iron wire (also known as resistance wire or heating wire), apply a few amps, and isolation, or use specially designed trace heating wire, see one of the answers below.

Comment: Another answer, is to use a big-**s electric heater, and a plug-in thermostat. You can find thermostats that adjust all the way down to freezing temperature, and you can find non-adjustable thermostats that are designed specifically to keep a space just above freezing. Just plug the thermostat into an outlet, and plug the heater into the thermostat. (Make sure it's a "dumb" heater that will come on as soon as it's plugged in instead of waiting for you to push a button.) https://www.amazon.com/dp/B074HVYDV1/ (Note! I'm not recommending this specific product. Just want to show the type.)

Answer (score 32):

The lifetime of an incandescent bulb goes roughly inversely as the 14th power of the voltage (was a 'fact' I remembered from somewhere in my dark engineering past). If you use two bulbs in series, so each sees half the voltage, you can assume they will last 'for ever'.

With the bulbs lasting a very long time, the premise of the question becomes moot.

[This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamp_rerating) gives the lifetime voltage exponent as between -12 and -16. I would imagine the range is to cover all the variations for vacuum to inert gas to halogen fill, wattage, envelope size, materials other than tungsten for the filament, etc. Whether the exponent is -12 or -16, 0.5 raised to that power is fairly big, and it doesn't matter to you whether your rated 1000 hours becomes 4096000 or 65536000 hours.

The power of a filament bulb, due to the large positive tempco of the filament, only goes as the 1.5 power of the voltage, not squared as for constant value resistors. You would therefore want two 40 watt bulbs in series to give you a total of 25 watts.

Those of you who are old enough might remember the brief appearance of '2000 hour' light bulbs on the market. They were designed to run slightly cooler, so lasted longer. They were in response to a feeling among consumers that light bulb companies were designing bulbs to fail quickly, in only 1000 hours, so that we would have to buy more bulbs. Because it ran cooler, the 2000 hour bulb was much less efficient. In terms of pure cost for light, it was cheaper to buy two 1000 hour bulbs and have them run more efficiently, the savings in electricity more than making up the cost difference. They only survived in niche applications where it was very expensive to change a bulb, for instance when the luminaire needed specialist access equipment to reach it.

This illustrates the benefit of analysing what is really needed. If you want **light** from a filament bulb, you need to operate it as hot as possible, until the lifetime becomes a problem. If you want **heat** from a filament bulb, you can run it much cooler, and it will last for ever.

Comment: +1 for knowing what wattage bulbs to put in series to get 25W.

Comment: @colintd You may or may not be old enough to remember that there used to be '2000 hour' bulbs on the market, which weren't quite as efficient (aka yet more inefficient) as standard 1000 hour bulbs, as they ran just slightly cooler. In my teens, I made a 'photoflood' temperature bulb by using a standard 1000 hour mains bulb and running it from full wave filtered rectified mains, which gave it a roughly 1 hour lifetime. It was clever than that, switchable 1/2 wave for cool setup, full wave for standard tungsten temp, and switched in a filter capacitor to get 1.4 * rms mains for photography.

Comment: I always use voltage sensitive components to protect my fuses

Comment: @Neil_UK You gave it a 1 hour lifetime, or was that a typo?

Comment: If two bulbs in series should last virtually forever, why wasn't it more common to put say two ordinary 100W bulbs in series to get a 60W bulb that never burned out?

Comment: @Michael because the efficiency gets even worse.  Running bulbs cooler means even less of the light is in the visible range.  Series connected loads are also not something electricians normally do, and for smaller lamps built in to things (usually as indicators) there are other ways, like a series diode or just a lamp built for a higher voltage (or just long life)

Comment: And if you want a really reliable setup use an H-bridge - two bulbs in parallel, in series with another two bulbs in parallel.

Comment: @Michael In short, you get 60W worth of heat, but much less than 60W-equivalent of visible light.

Comment: You should explain how the 2nd bulb works after the first one fails; i.e. when the failed filament burns, this creates an open circuit, and in an open circuit, no current flows; therefore no redundancy.

Comment: @Seamus They're in parallel so current continues to flow after the first one burns out.

Comment: @CareyGregory: OK - makes sense - except for the fact that the author says ***in series***; he actually says it twice!  Maybe someone should edit this for him?

Comment: @Seamus Isn't the whole point that they won't (or are extremely unlikely to) burn out?

Comment: @Seamus Two bulbs IN SERIES see half the voltage each, so will last forever. This makes the question moot, you don't have to worry about bulb failure. The fuse issue I mentioned was perhaps a distraction. When I worked for an energy company designing smart meters, they had a computer-controlled jig of filament bulbs creating time-varying loads. The jig would frequently (like evry 1000 hours / # of bulbs) blow a bulb, which would then tke out the rest of the jig in the middle of the night. Series bulbs would have worked far better.

Comment: @Neil_UK: If bulbs' filament burns out/through, that creates an open circuit. Current does not flow through open circuit. Maybe you should draw a schematic, but that's the way things work.

Comment: @Seamus If bulbs' filament burns out/through, that creates an open circuit. If bulbs' filament does not burn out/through, then current keeps flowing. My answer uses the 'does not burn out' technique.

Comment: Arguing that a filament 'does not burn out' is a rather silly argument, but quite popular it seems.

Comment: @Seamus, the low estimate for two 40-watt bulbs in series is that they'll last five centuries.  On a merely human timescale, that's the same thing as "does not burn out".

Comment: We're just not used to this sort of scaling factor. I can't think of another example of anything scaling with such a high power of a variable, except a rather contrived case from my line of work: the throughout of an optical system of *n* mirrors each with reflectivity *r* is *r^n*. Even with *r*=90%, the losses soon mount up if you've got a dozen mirrors

Comment: @Seamus Youneed a frame shift. Instead of thinking 'light bulb', think 'removable heating device with self-indicating function'. You can run this device at 240 V, when it will last for 6 weeks, and deal with the predicted failure, or run it at 120 V, when it will outlast your great great great grandchildren. However, this device is not rated for 120 V operation, because people usually want the self-indicating side effect rather than the heat, or have done in the past.

Comment: @Neil_UK: I feel that your estimates of lifetime are *optimistic*; there are other failure mechanisms that you're not considering.  But all of this may be beside the point as it doesn't actually address the OP's question: *"I want to make a circuit that will sense when the bulb burns out..."*. Nevertheless, credit's due to you for good "out of the box" thinking wrt a solution.

Comment: This bulb lasted at least 110 years. It runs at a low temperature, similar to what you might get with 2 modern bulbs in series. https://www.lightbulbs.com/blog/worlds-oldest-light-bulb-that-still-works

Answer (score 19):

Rather than a lightbulb, there are better solutions.  They're probably also cheaper than the extra parts you'd need to build a suitable mains-rated circuit.

**Low wattage heaters:** There are various low-power heaters designed for this application.  I know them as [tube/tubular heaters](https://www.screwfix.com/c/heating-plumbing/heaters/cat831056?calcheaterproducttype=tubular).  They're also sold for use [inside pianos](https://www.pianocoversonline.co.uk/products/m215-damp-chaser-piano-heater) and [greenhouses](https://www.qbicheating.co.uk/hylite-thermostatic-greenhouse-heater.html).  The latter have a higher power rating, but also have a thermostat so they won't run more than necessary.

**Trace heat tape:** There's also [trace heat tape](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/hvac-fans-thermal-management/electronics-heating-cooling-components/trace-heating-cable/) which is wrapped around the pipes at risk (typically in attics and outbuildings).  It delivers the heat exactly where it's needed, and some types can be applied under insulation, but it's not so useful if you have tanks, taps, or drain traps to consider.

**Trickery with lighting products:** If you really want to build something, I'd connect the 2nd bulb to a dusk-to-dawn sensor illuminated by the first bulb, in a darkened room: when the first goes dark, the 2nd comes on.  If the room can't be darkened enough, restricting the light  that can fall on the sensor would help.

Comment: As no one else had given the frame challenge answer, I though I would - but a way of doing what the OP actually asked for as a bonus, if the room can be kept dark.

Comment: Another option for buying low wattage heaters is small heating pads for reptiles. They're available in flexible mat form for $10-20, often with a thermostat.

Comment: I hadn't even known about tubular heaters that use a lamp socket. Thanks for this recommendation! It sounds ideal for OP, and a good way to keep my bathroom a bit warmer throughout the winter. Cheers!

Comment: @lucas I've never seen them with lamp connectors in the UK but do have an ancient (and probably illegal these days) connector I'd be happy to use for suitable currents.

Comment: The trace heat tape is the correct "smart" solution. The intelligence is in the termperature coefficient of the metallic conductors, that regulates power such that it mainly produces heat when the temperature is low. We don't just worry about your bulb burning out in winter, but also about wasting energy which in most cases is linked to CO2 emissions. Besides, if you are familiar with the heroic efforts of Edison cs to build a lamp with a usable service time, it is a shame to use light bulbs just to produce heat. A piece of cheap iron wire will do for you, just add some isolation

Comment: @Roland,yes, if it's fairly accessible pipes. Low power heaters are likely to be more appropriate in some cases

Answer (score 2):

You can of course build a current-detection with a relay to switch over, but I see some challenges.
What happens when the second also burns out?

An alternative solution can be to put 3 10W lamps in parallel, when one blows you still have 20W, till you check it.